# How to parse string and consume it according to different defined patterns in java?

Tags: java, parsing, design-patterns, pattern-matching

I have a case where the user should define different patterns for a string like places locations in a configuration file, for example:

```html
<place-name>
<place-name>, <place-location>
<place-name>, <place-location>, <city>
<place-name>, <place-location>, <city>, <country>
<place-name>, <place-location>, <country>
```

**NOTE:The pattern shouldn't be limited to the above patterns only, it should be defined dynamically by the user as a configuration and it can be extended to tens of patterns.**

Some of tags have a list of possible values to be able to differentiate between patterns with the same structure like the 3rd and 5th patterns where the user should define a list of possible values for city and country, for example

```html
<city> = Abilene | Akron | Albuquerque | Alexandria | Allentown | Anaheim | Anchorage | Ann Arbor | Antioch | Arlington | Arvada| Aurora | Austin | Bakersfield| Baltimore | Bangor ...

<country> = USA | U.S. | United States | U.K. ...
```

According to these configuration, the end user should be able to write a string then it should be parsed by the program according to one of the defined patterns.

For example, if the end user write:

```html
Disneyland Park, 1313 Disneyland Dr. , Anaheim, United States
```

The tool should be able to match it with the below pattern

```html
<place-name>, <place-location>, <city>, <country>
```

Then these info. should be used later in the program for further processing.

How this issue could be handled in java? and Is there a straightforward way for that?

Comment: You could use en existing method, such as XML and Schemas. If you want to do this in a custom and extensible way, you will almost certainly need a lexer/parser.

Comment: I have seen a *library* for this but forget. Maybe you should look for some libraries.

Comment: @BoristheSpider could you please provide example for the lexer/parser that can be used to handle the described case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are describing is a "lexical parser" which is typically used for parsing "code" into a instruction tree..

The most commonly used one is called YACC, but since you are using java I would have to say that antlr is probbably your best bet. (antlr is a java port of yacc. )

Comment: I have check ANTLR but as I see it takes a grammar file as input and generates two classes: lexer and parser. In my case, the rules should be defined in a configuration file in order to be extendable, the tool shouldn't regenerate the lexer and parser classes in each time the rules changes. Please, if possible give me example on the grammar that can be used to handle my described example.

Comment: @vanilla you misunderstand. You have _two_ languages here - you will need one lexer/parser for the config file syntax descriptor. You would parse the config file syntax, then use that to generate _another_ lexer/parser combination to parse the actual file.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Yes, I got your point. There should be no problem in the first part for parsing the config. file but for the second part, using library like ANTLR, it uses the grammar file to generate lexer & parser (.java files), then these files should be compiled before using them. So, each time the user adds a new rule, I'll need to regenerate the lexer & parser again. Is there a way to use the grammar file directly or I have to write my own lexer/parser? if you have a good example describing the second part, please point me to it because I'm new in this area.